# Method to format HDD with a USB (Without boot into window install Just DOS on boot screen)

Tags: boot, usb, formatting

anyone know how to like

i want to plug the Flash Drive in then PC boot from it then   DOS come up  press Enter 2-3 times and Everything Gone.  :)

i try to find this

and alway end up with method to make  bootable then use it from window install tool

thank you

i try to make this 32 mb super old flash drive of me useful for my work( i have to like format hundreds of PC to blank state in next week)

Comment: There's a good reason user input is needed for formatting a disk. You generally regret it if you make a mistake.

Comment: yes i'm aware of that i try to make my 32 mb usb drive get most of it as much as possible :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Darik's Boot and Nuke](http://www.dban.org/)

"DBAN is a self-contained boot disk that automatically deletes the contents of any hard disk that it can detect."

Be careful because it will format ALL hard disks in the system.